# PrepareStatement JDBC in java

Tags: java, jdbc

Are PrepareStatement only usable with values? 
Example: Could I use something like `con.prepareStatement(SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE name =?)` 
Or `?` is used only for values, thus within the clause `WHEWRE`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

PreparedStatement is only applicable on values. And that is the reason why setters are provided ONLY for different kind of IN values.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use placeholders for table or column names. They are just used for values. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html